# QGIS Split Vector Layer By Multiple Attributes

Tags: fields-attributes, splitting, split-by-attribute, multiple, attribute-splitter

I am working on a fiber network file and would like to be able to split a point shapefile by multiple attributes, three to be exact. I can "Select Features by Value" and export each one but I can only do this one at a time, I would have to manually do this approximately 1728 times. I can "Split Vector Layer" but this only allows me to select one value, I need three (tube, strand, port). I thought about exporting it to a CSV file, but this would create 1728 CSV files to import. Is there a feature, plugin, or script that exists for this? I have not run any scripts yet, so if this is an option can you point me to a tutorial?

[image: Attributes Table]

The goal is to be able to quickly identify each Splice Point by Tube, Stand and number of Ports:
[image: Styles]

Comment: You could merge your 1728 layers into one then do the splitting/extraction to three layers on that, then split those by the layer name value.

Comment: Currently all "1728" are one Shapefile, I am trying to find an easy way to split them into the 1728 possible combinations to be able to easily identify them by changing their style. I have updated this with an image showing the few I have been able to do by using "Select Features by Value" and export each one individually. Unfortunately this is the slow method.

Comment: I've answered below, but I think you may have what's known as an [X/Y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). If you want different symbology per group of values, use categorized symbology on one layer.

Answer (score 0):

Create  virtual field that concatenates your three attributes, then use the [Split vector layer](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#qgissplitvectorlayer) processing tool:

[image]

[image]